# What are the drawbacks of implementing functions using Varargs?

Tags: java, arrays, function

Using variable arguments allows for one function declaration which can operate on a variable number of input arguments of the same type. This can be used in conjunction with a `for:each` loop in order to perform some operation using all of the input arguments.

Looking through the `java.lang.Math` it seems that `max`, `min`, and `hypot`, would all be more useful if implemented using varargs. Instead they are each defined to only work on exactly 2 input arguments.

An example of a function that makes sense to be implemented with varargs would be an averaging function.

```
public static double average(double... numbers) {
    double total = 0.0;

    for (double d : numbers) {
        total += d;
    }

    return total / numbers.length;
}
```

My question is, what drawbacks are there to implementing functions using varargs? Why is it that most libraries included in the JDK do not utilize varargs when applicable?

Comment: You need to look at the design choices by not forgetting history. Varargs were introduced in Java 5, and Math.max() exists since Java 1.0. Varargs also have a cost: each invocation necessitates the creation of a new array.

Comment: Note that the current implementation of `average(double...)` in this post allows the caller to provide zero arguments. The question rises: what is the average of nothing?

Comment: @MC Emperor That could be fixed with `average(double d, double ... numbers)` though, right?  This would require at least 1 `double` to be passed.  I think a similar fix could work in a lot of cases.  The downside would be needing to accommodate for that value instead of being able to iterate through every value with a simple `for-each`.

Answer (score 0):

varargs is simply syntactic sugar to wrap multiple arguments provided in a function into an array and then to pass that array into the function. What's good about it? It potentially saves some time from having to code up the manual wrap. What are the drawbacks? Using your same example of max and min, these methods were added in Java 1.0, before they added varargs. And maintaining backwards compatibility is a good thing in general

Comment: Backwards compatibility would still be maintained though. Since all old calls to the function use it with 2 arguments, redefining the function to use unknown arguments should have no adverse effects on the 2 argument calls.

Comment: @Karson that would work for source-compatibility: you recompile, and it still compiles fine. But binary compatibility would be lost (you don't recompile, but use the newer method taking a vararg). They could add an additional method taking a vararg, but this use-case is rare enough, and already covered by Collections.max, Stream.max, etc.